# Acer Aspire S7-391: No bootable device

Tags: windows, boot, ssd, raid, acer-aspire

After [fixing the motherboard](https://superuser.com/questions/1038508/acer-aspire-s7-391-bios-recovery) of my Acer Aspire S7-391 i tried to boot it from the stock SSD. However, i get a screen which lists the details of RAID Volume and Physical Devices. The last line says "Press  to enter configuration utility..." for a couple of seconds after which it posts "No bootable disk found - please restart".

These are the details of RAID Volumes

ID: 0 / Name: HDD0 / Level: RAID0(Stripe) / Strip: 64KB / Size: 238.5 GB / Status: Normal / Bootable: Yes

And the details of Physical Devices

ID: 0 / Device Model: KINGSTON SMSR150 / Serial #: xxxx / Size: 119.2 GB / Type/Status(Vol ID): Member Disk(0)

ID: 1 / Device Model: KINGSTON SMSR150 / Serial #: xxxx / Size: 119.2 GB / Type/Status(Vol ID): Member Disk(0)

What am i supposed to do to boot into windows?

Comment: aim it?  You did go back through the bios and remake all the settings that had it bootable , and in the boot order, and any uefi (or legasy) boot settings, and raid (or compatable) sata settings?     "No bootable disk found - please restart". this is just not finding the system boot or OS disk, or in the order or configuration it was in. Also you could remove anything else it might try to boot to, the boot order also fixing that (if that was the issue)   Your array is still assembled , that is good. You do have 2 SSDs in a raid0 configuration?  (on a laptop?)

Comment: I did not disturb any RAID configuration. The SSD is mSATA and i think it has 2 SSDs of 120GB soldered onto it. I did change some BIOS settings earlier when it was working. When I used the recovery disk to refresh the computer, it said the disk is locked and cannot refresh. Maybe ill try to revert the BIOS settings to original and try to boot.

Comment: UPDATE: I did change my settings from Legacy back to UEFI and it booted right away. Did a disk check and performed some automatic repair.

Comment: so you fixed it?  If you did please self-answer the question, with a full explaination as to how you solutioned the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved soon after i made the following changes.

Start up and enter BIOS settings with Fn+F2 combination. Go to the Boot tab and change the priority order in such a way that the SSD is 1st in boot order. Change the boot settings to UEFI and save and exit. The laptop switched on without any errors now.