# HP 630 black screen and bricked

Tags: bios

I have a HP 630 that is black screen and I believe it is bricked.

I tried removing battery, ram and tried to install bios through USB but nothing is working no blinking on USB just USB light stays on. windows+B, FN+B none of the method is working.

Then I tried to flash bios chip directly with USB Programmer CH341A Series Burner Chip 24 EEPROM BIOS LCD Writer 25 SPI Flash , download the bios from http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5086783&swItemId=ob_129448_1&swEnvOid=405... and tried 03672.fd, 03674.fd, 03676.fd one by one but no good luck.

The laptop is turning on and GPU chip getting hot I think little bit more hotter than it suppose to be but not sure, if I turn off the laptop still the GPU chip kept hot.

Is it the bios problem or something wrong with the GPU chip?

I attached the actual board and bios chip picture.

I found two windbond chip on the board one is located opposite side of the GPU chip slightly bigger than the other one and I believe this is the bios chip showing in picture-1 attachment. And the other one is windbond as well located beside of the ram slightly smaller than the other in picture-2 attachment.

[image: mother board image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to a failed capacitor on your motherboard. [Here's what happened](https://superuser.com/questions/1038508/acer-aspire-s7-391-bios-recovery) to my laptop recently and solved the issue by testing it with an electronics guy.

Edit: Link corrected.

Do the motherboard continuity test with a simple multimeter and you might figure out if there's an issue with your board.